# Changing contents of ArrayAdapter do not get updated

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Clearing or adding data does not get updated in the method addData in my custom ArrayAdapter class. What is going on? I have also tried updating the List which is fed into the ArrayAdapter and that does not get changed either, both times the amount of items in the adapter stay the same. Please help!

Class:

```
package sukh.app.ireddit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * While this looks like a lot of code, all this class
 * actually does is load the posts in to the listview.
 * 
 * @author Hathy 
 */
public class PostsFragment extends Fragment{

    ListView postsList;
    PostAdapter adapter;
    Handler handler;
    Activity activity;

    String subreddit;
    List<Post> posts;
    PostsHolder postsHolder;

    public PostsFragment(){
        handler=new Handler();
        posts=new ArrayList<Post>();
        activity=getActivity();
    }    

    public static Fragment newInstance(String subreddit){
        PostsFragment pf=new PostsFragment();
        pf.subreddit=subreddit;
        pf.postsHolder=new PostsHolder(pf.subreddit);        
        return pf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts
                                , container
                                , false);
        postsList=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){
        // This should run only once for the fragment as the
        // setRetainInstance(true) method has been called on
        // this fragment

        if(posts.size()==0){

            // Must execute network tasks outside the UI
            // thread. So create a new thread.

            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    posts.addAll(postsHolder.fetchPosts());

                    // UI elements should be accessed only in
                    // the primary thread, so we must use the
                    // handler here.

                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            createAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }else{
            createAdapter();
        }
    }
   /**
     * This method creates the adapter from the list of posts
     * , and assigns it to the list.
     */
    private void createAdapter(){

        // Make sure this fragment is still a part of the activity.
        if(getActivity()==null) return;

        adapter=new PostAdapter(posts);
        postsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("sukh", "setting adapter");
        postsList.setOnScrollListener(adapter);
    }

    protected class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> implements OnScrollListener {
        private int previousTotal = 0;
        private boolean loading = true;
        //PostAdapter _adapter = this;

        public PostAdapter(List<Post> posts){
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.post_item, posts);
        }   

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_item, null);
            }

            Post thePost = getItem(position);

            TextView postTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            postTitleTextView.setText(thePost.getTitle());

            TextView postDetailsTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_details);
            postDetailsTextView.setText(thePost.getDetails());

            TextView postScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_score);
            postScoreTextView.setText(thePost.getScore());

            return convertView;
        }

        private void addData() {
            //final List<Post> newPosts = new ArrayList<Post>();
            Log.i("update1", this.adapterToString());
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    //neither of these following statements make a difference
                    //neither does posts.clear() or posts.addAll...
                    //adapter.addAll(postsHolder.fetchMorePosts());
                    adapter.clear();
                }
            };
            Log.i("sukh", "executed scroll");       
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("update2", this.adapterToString());
        }

        private String adapterToString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int total = this.getCount();
            sb.append("contents: ");
            /*for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i ++) {
                sb.append(this.getItem(i).title + "/n");
            }*/
            //return sb.toString();
            return sb.append(total).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;     
                }
            }

            if (!loading && 
                    (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + 1 >= totalItemCount)
                    ) {
                addData();
                loading = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
    }


}
```

**EDIT:** fixed. Added new class that extends ASyncTask and had it fetchMorePosts before updating the adapter.

Class is shown :

```
private class AddPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i("update2", "start fetchMorePosts");
            posts.addAll(postsHolder.fetchMorePosts());
            Log.i("update2", "end fetchMorePosts");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i("update2", "start adapterChange");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("update2", "start adapterChange");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your addData function, you're clearing adapter in a thread 'after' notifyDataSetChanged() is called.

Comment: it's unknown. you shouldn't assume the order. also noticed you are creating a thread yet not starting it.